# Help establishing a polymorphic relationship in the models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

**Models:**

```
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :threaded, :through => :threaded, :foreign_key => :thread_id

class ThreadFeed < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :threaded, :polymorphic => true
```

**Model Fields**

```
Thread (id)
ThreadFeed (id, thread_id, threaded_id, threaded_type)
```

Problem is with:

```
@thread.threaded
```

Rails is using (threaded_id, threaded_type) as the foreign key and I want thread_id to be the foreign key.

Comment: Hmmm... polymorphic through relationships can get tricky.  Can you describe more about what you are try to do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this Railscast, [Polymorphism](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

It will give you a better insight into how Polymorphism works.

First issue I notice is that it should be through :threadfeed, not :threaded

```
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :threadfeeds, :as => :threaded
```

In the Railscast, he has:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  #...
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

Comment: Did you watch the whole thing? It talks about the associations for all of the models. Do you have the join model, which belongs_to: thread?

Comment: Update with better details. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks but that does not work. in the logs I now see: 'ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: thread_feeds.threadfeeds_id: SELECT "thread_feeds".* FROM "thread_feeds" WHERE ("thread_feeds".threadfeeds_id = 77 AND "thread_feeds".threadfeeds_type = 'Wall')'

Comment: I want the where column to be only (thread_id = 77) not sure why the type "wall" is still there I don't want that. thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that Thread doesn't know what feed is:

```
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :feeds, :through => :thread_feeds, :as => :feeded
    has_many :thread_feeds

class ThreadFeed < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :feeded, :polymorphic => true
```

The second problem is the complexity of polymorphic.  Here's a great article on it: http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/3/polymorphic-through